# How to grab the required value input on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For example, there is such a JS-code:

> function openAlbum() {
>   $("#tracks").html('Some text...');
>   var uid = $("#uid").val();
>
> ```
>    $.ajax({
>             type: "POST",
>             url: "s.php",
>             data: "uid="+uid,
>             success: function(html) {
>                     $("#results").empty();
>                     $("#results").append(html);
>             }
>     }); }
> ```

And this html/php-code that is displayed in a cycle:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($searchAlbum); $i++) {
echo '<div id="cover"><form action=""><input type="hidden" id="uid" value="'.str_replace('https://example.com/', '', $searchAlbum[$i]->href).'"/><a href="#" onclick="openAlbum();"><img src="'.$searchAlbum[$i]->images[1]->url.'"/></a><br><br><span>'.$searchAlbum[$i]->name.'</span><input type="submit" style="position: absolute;;left: -99999px;" /></form></div>';
}
```

**Problem:** currently by clicking grabs only the first input value on the page with id="uid".

How do I put a JS var uid value from the div, which clicked a link?

P.S. Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: `id`s must be unique. That is probably part of the problem.

Comment: Better not to use onclick but to add an event listener that will be fired when any instance of the cover div is clicked. Then you can get the value with 'this'.

Comment: I don't fully understand what you're trying to do so I don't currently fully support the forms, but I'm going to trust you! Take a look at the answer I gave it should give you a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to change the way you kinda do this a bit...

```
<?php
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($searchAlbum); $i++) {
?>
         <div class="cover">
               <form action="">
                   <input type="hidden" class="uid" value="<?php echo str_replace('https://example.com/', '', $searchAlbum[$i]->href); ?>"/>
                  <img src="<?php echo $searchAlbum[$i]->images[1]->url; ?>"/>
                  <span><?php echo $searchAlbum[$i]->name; ?></span>
                  <input type="submit" style="position: absolute;left: -99999px;" />
               </form>
         </div>';
<?php
    }
?>
```

Script:

```
$(document).on('click','.cover img',openAlbum);
function openAlbum() { 
   $("#tracks").html('Some text...'); var uid = $(this).parent().find('.uid').val();

   $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "s.php",
            data: "uid="+uid,
            success: function(html) {
                    //$("#results").empty();
                    //$("#results").append(html);
                      $("#results").html(html);
            }
    }); 
}
```

This should cover everything. I switched all ids to classes and changed how you execute your jQuery.

Comment: Let me know if by chance the function doesn't work. Unless you are using that function in more than one place it is kinda a waste to use it this way. I would really create it as `$(document).(...,...,function(){...});`

Comment: Thank you very much!
This is partly solved my problem, but at the same time there are new.
After the click, we send the data to the page s.php, process them and show in div - this div can arbitrarily refresh. Up to several times :(

Comment: @Kruazzan Can you be a little more specific. I changed the part where `#results` (assuming) div content is replaced. Check out [html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your help!
As a result, I will be able to solve the problem.

JS-code:

```
function openAlbum(uid)
{
$("#results").html('Some text...');

       $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "s.php",
                data: "uid="+uid,
                success: function(html) {
                        $("#results").empty();
                        $("#results").append(html);
                }
        });

}
```

HTML-code:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($searchAlbum); $i++) {
?>
<div id="cover"><a href="#" onclick='openAlbum("<? echo $searchAlbum[$i]->id; ?>");'><img src="<? echo $searchAlbum[$i]->images[1]->url; ?>"/></a><br><br><span><? echo $searchAlbum[$i]->name; ?></span></div>
<?
}
```

Comment: Ok looks like you added an answer here which makes more sense. In this case just get rid of the first `.html` it isn't necessary. You really only want to change it on `success` in most cases. Or you can add a fail clause. But this looks good overall. STILL should change your ids to classes if you expect them to repeat. In this case "cover" is created at least once, but can be created indefinitely. You should make it a class.

Answer (score 0):

Since id in HTML must be unique, it is taking only the first element's value. Make the ids unique or use class attribute as Cayce K has answered.